# Add new column using case_when of other column in R

Tags: r, datetime, if-statement, dplyr, case-when

I want to add a column to my data frame which takes values such as "mon", "tue", "wed", "thu" etc. depending on another column containing a "date time" variable, but I can't use the weekdays function as it also depends on the time of the day.

I.e. if the column created_at is between: 2021-03-01 09:00:00 and 2021-03-02 09:00:00 then the new column should classify as "mon".

If on the other hand the created_at is between 2021-03-02 09:00:00 and 2021-03-03 09:00:00 it should
classify as "tue".

And so on for the rest of the week. (following the hours of the stock market)

[image: Sample data]

Comment: Please use `dput` to show example data

Comment: Does the stock market always open at 0900? If so, just subtract 9 hours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(
    result = wday(created_at - hours(9), label = TRUE)
  )
```

If you have issues, please post a reproducible sample of data using `dput()`.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked!
Do you know if I could change the wday fucntion to give me the abbreviation of the weekday in english? I think it is following my computer which means I got it in my national language.

Comment: add `locale = "English_United States.1252"` as an argument to `wday`